# Convert htaccess to nginx rewrite with subfolder

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess file with apache in every subfolder project specific.
Example http://www.website.com/projecta/subfolder/.htaccess

With apache this isn't a problem to make a rewrite, now with nginx it doesn't seems that obvious:

Old .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on<br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br/>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br/>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1
```

I tried several option, but non of them seems to accept the structure:

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?rt=$1 break;
    }
}
```

Remark: each subfolder had a .htaccess file, while this configuration is on a global level. I don't know how to parse `projecta/subfolder/` each time.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below

```
location / {
   rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1/$2/index.php?rt=$3 break;
}
```